# How to calculate non-stoichiometric ratio

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

I'm reading a paper "Photocatalysis-mediated drug-free sustainable
cancer therapy using nanocatalyst." Here, the authors synthetise nanoplates of $\ce{SnS_{1.68}}$ with nanodots of $\ce{WO_{2.41}}$.

The authors said the valence state for $\ce{Sn}$ are $\ce{Sn^{4+}:Sn^{2+}} = 0.681:0.319$ so the non-stoichiometric ratio of $\ce{Sn:S}$ is $1:1.68$.

For the $\ce{WO_{2.41}}$ they said, valence state for $\ce{W}$ are $\ce{W^{6+}:W^{5+}:W^{4+}} = 0.307:0.216:0.477 $ so the non-stoichiometric ratio of $\ce{W:O}$ is $1:2.41$.

I would like to know where the 1.68 and 2.41 numbers come from.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try averaging over the multiple valences?

Comment: @MaxW no, I don't have any idea how to get that values, if I average the valences what I should do next?

Comment: Huh? There's nothing to calculate - these are experimental values.

Comment: @Mithoron I get this information just from the experiment? But there is a way to get that proportion or the software to analyze the data do all the work?

Comment: 1.68 and 2.41 may come from element analysis. I would be rather interested in where 0.307, 0.216 and 0.477 come from. As many combinations are possible with W : O 2.41.  With these 3 numbers given, the total W : O ratio is determined by them. Possibly X-ray analysis of different states of W atoms ? Or they mixed different W oxides ?

Comment: The numbers come from *observation* of the compounds, presumably by elemental analysis. They are experimentally observed results not theoretical calculations.

Comment: @Poutnik they used XPS to find the oxidation state of each one and find that proportion in their system

Comment: @matt_black thanks for the clarification

Comment: So W : O would be 0.307 * 3 + 0.216 * 2.5 + 0.477 * 2 = 2.415. Similarly Sn : S ratio is 0.681 * 2 + 0.319 * 1 = 1.681. XFS and elementary analysis are 2 independent ways how to get these numbers.